# How to create dynamic class with dynamic member

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have to apply serverfiltering on kendo grid datasource, this kendo grid needs a model class for that datasource to perform filter operation. Problem here is, this grid binding with dynamic datasource which is getting from mongoDB as bsondocument. now i need to create a class model and into that i have to create members dynamically for each columns of the datasource.

```
public class DynamicModelClass
    {
        public DynamicModelClass(string name, Type type)
        {
          this.FieldName = name;
          this.FieldType = type;
        }

       public string FieldName;
       public Type FieldType;
    }

var fields = new List<DynamicModelClass>() {
            new DynamicModelClass("EmployeeID", typeof(int)),
            new DynamicModelClass("EmployeeName", typeof(string)),
            new DynamicModelClass("Designation", typeof(string))
        };

        dynamic obj = new DynamicClass(fields);
```

how to create class and how to built dynamic members into that class, like following,

```
public class DynamicClass
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mark { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string department { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
```

}

_id, id, name, mark, Gender, department, date these are dynamic columns from mongoDB.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Either you create a class, which is a compile-time known definition, or you create a dynamic object at runtime

Comment: i need to create dynamic property into that class.